# I can't find the equivalent for 撞衫, could you help?

Tags: meaning

It looks like this phrase means two persons wear the same or similar outfit, which is very embarrasing. But the word "uniform" seems not to serve such purpose because uniform doesn't make the wearers embarrassing.

Comment: Are you asking about English or Chinese?

Comment: [撞衫](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%92%9E%E8%A1%AB)

Comment: @– user3a 撞 in 撞衫 is the same one in **撞**期 (scheduling **conflict**) 撞衫 is not a loaned word  from English "dress same".  The answer is wrong in the linked site.

Comment: I asked this on English SE: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/369645/68094

Answer (score 3):

> [撞衫](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/50983/) *often used to describe movie stars, celebrity's who just happen to wear the same outfit*

'撞' in '撞衫' is the same one in '撞期' (scheduling conflict).

> '撞期'(date clash) means two events scheduled at the same date, creating a **scheduling conflict** between them. It is "(two scheduled events) dates run into each other" in English.
>
> '撞衫' (dress clash) means two people wearing identical outfits at the same event, creating a **fashion faux pas** for both. It is "(two people) dress the same" in English.

I suggest simply translate 撞衫 as "**dress the same**" or "**identically dress**"

For example:

- "安和瑪麗在頒獎典禮上**撞了衫**" (Ann and Mary **dressed the same** at the award show);
- "穿成衣可能導致與某人**撞衫**" (wear ready-to-wear dress many resulted in **dressing the same** with someone)

Comment: I guess this phrase comes from Hong Kong or overseas Chinese, because 衫 is not often used in normal mandarin. But what this phrase interests me is that it also implies the unexpected embarrassment of the wearers, and "dress the same" simply describes what happens.

Comment: @NanningYouth, 衫 is commonly used in 衣衫, 羊毛衫，衬衫... ... 撞衫 itself does not connote embarrassment. Sometimes, it could be funny, interesting, it really depends on one's point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Tang Ho's answer is good

---

literally it's clothing clashing, or just translate as "dress the same"

haha, in Chinese spoken language we also use 撞衫 a lot to describe wearing the same dress as others not only movie stars